# Bootstrap datepicker date highlighting issue

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Hi i am wanting to highlight a range of days in Bootstrap datepicker. I am wanting to create an availability calendar.

For e.g. i want to highlight 10/10/2013, 11/10/2013, 12/10/2013,

So far i have

`$('#avialCalendar').datepicker({
            startDate: startDate,
            endDate: "10/10/2015",
            daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,1,2,3,4,5,6"
        });`

to highlight my dates do i have to go

```
$('#avialCalendar').datepicker("setDate", "10/10/2013");
$('#avialCalendar').datepicker("setDate", "11/10/2013");
$('#avialCalendar').datepicker("setDate", "12/10/2013");
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, by default [**Bootstrap datepicker**](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=1&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox) does not have this features of selecting multiple dates.

However  date range picker is possible using [**Dan Grossman's fork**](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker) of bootstrap.

You can check this [demo](http://www.dangrossman.info/2012/08/20/a-date-range-picker-for-twitter-bootstrap/)

[image]